# My table is not updating properly in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a function called GetGridCuentas that Calls on the context to get the data to be displayed in my table. It works the first time but after that, it keeps getting the same table and it's not changing.

To be more specific, when I select a new table by changing the variable "EmpresaSeleccionadaValida" from null to the Code of the company that I wanted it works the first time and it gives me the desired table. Now, after the first time that I do it and I try to select another company it gives me the same result (the previous company's filtered rows) back. Sometimes, when the second company has more rows, those extra rows are added, but the new ones are not replaced. Even when I go back to null and change back the company code it still does not work. I know it's not that EmpreseaSeleccionadaValida is not changing because I saw in the debugger how it was a different value. The query just gives me the same list as the first time that I run it.

This is the method that gives me trouble:

```
    private async Task GetGridCuentas()
    {
        Cuentas = new List<planes_cuentas>();
        Console.WriteLine(Cuentas);
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            signeduser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(user);
            Console.WriteLine(Cuentas);
            Console.WriteLine(EmpresaSeleccionadaValida);
            var query = await _context.planes_cuentas
            .Where(x => x.CDGO_EMPRSA == EmpresaSeleccionadaValida)
            .Distinct().OrderBy(n => n.CDGO_CNTA).ToListAsync();
            Cuentas = query;
            Console.WriteLine(EmpresaSeleccionadaValida);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Cuentas);
    }
```

This is the rest of the page's code for context:

```
@page "/Grid"
@using BusinessERPWeb.Data
@using BusinessERPWeb.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService
@layout MainLayout
@inject DataContext _context
@attribute [Authorize]
<div class="GridMenuContainer">
    <div class="ButtonsContainer">
        <button class="IconButton" @onclick="GetGridCuentas">
            <span class="oi oi-reload Icon"></span>
            Refresh
        </button>
        <button class="IconButton @ColorToggled()" @onclick="ToggleEdit">
            <span class="oi oi-wrench Icon"></span>
            @if (IsEditing)
            {
                <span>Cancel Edit</span>
            }
            else
            {
                <span>Edit</span>
            }
        </button>
        <button class="IconButton" @onclick="SaveChanges">
            <span class="oi oi-data-transfer-upload Icon"></span>
            Save
        </button>
        <button class="IconButton">
            <span class="oi oi-circle-x Icon"></span>
            Delete
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="DropdownContainer">
        <Dropdown @bind-MenuItems="@Columnas" ButtonText="Seleccion de columnas" DropdownStyle="height: calc(20vh - 3.5rem);" />
    </div>
</div>


<div class="TableContainer">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 30px;" class="ColumnaSticky">
                    <input type="checkbox" unchecked @onchange="@(async (ArgumentosDeCambio) =>
               ToggleSelectAll(ArgumentosDeCambio))" />
                </th>
                <th class="ColumnaSticky" style="left: 29px">Codigo de cuenta</th>
                @foreach (var column in Columnas)
                {
                    if (column.Seleccionado)
                    {
                        <th>@column.Nombre</th>
                    }
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var cuenta in Cuentas.Where(c => c.NVEL_CNTA == 1)) // Render only top-level accounts initially
            {
                @RenderRow(cuenta);
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    public string? EmpresaSeleccionadaValida { get; set; }
    private string? AnteriorEmpresaSeleccionadaValida;
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }

    private List<string> ColumnasDisponibles = new List<string>();
    private List<string> ColumnasMostradas = new List<string>();
    private List<Columna> Columnas { get; set; } = new List<Columna>();

    private List<planes_cuentas> Cuentas = new List<planes_cuentas>();
    private ApplicationUser? signeduser = new ApplicationUser();

    /// <summary>
    /// Metodo que se llama cada vez que se cambian los parametros
    /// </summary>
    protected override async void OnParametersSet()
    {
        base.OnParametersSet();
        Console.WriteLine("TodosSeleccionados");
        if (EmpresaSeleccionadaValida != AnteriorEmpresaSeleccionadaValida)
        {
            AnteriorEmpresaSeleccionadaValida = EmpresaSeleccionadaValida;
            await GetGridCuentas();
        }
    }
    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(EmpresaSeleccionadaValida);
        foreach (var propiedad in typeof(planes_cuentas).GetProperties())
        {
            string StringPropiedad = propiedad.Name.ToString();
            if (StringPropiedad != "CDGO_CNTA" && StringPropiedad != "Seleccionado")
            {
                Columnas.Add(new Columna(false, StringPropiedad));
            }
        }
        await GetGridCuentas();
    }
    private async Task GetGridCuentas()
    {
        Cuentas = new List<planes_cuentas>();
        Console.WriteLine(Cuentas);
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            signeduser = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(user);
            Console.WriteLine(Cuentas);
            Console.WriteLine(EmpresaSeleccionadaValida);
            var query = await _context.planes_cuentas
            .Where(x => x.CDGO_EMPRSA == EmpresaSeleccionadaValida)
            .Distinct().OrderBy(n => n.CDGO_CNTA).ToListAsync();
            Cuentas = query;
            Console.WriteLine(EmpresaSeleccionadaValida);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Cuentas);
    }
    private void ToggleSelectAll(ChangeEventArgs ArgumentosDeCambio)
    {
        bool EstadoDeSeleccion = (bool)ArgumentosDeCambio.Value;
        foreach (var cuenta in Cuentas)
        {
            cuenta.Seleccionado = EstadoDeSeleccion;
        }
    }

    private void ActualizarColumnasMostradas(ChangeEventArgs ArgumentosDeCambio)
    {
        var ColumnasSeleccionadas = new List<string>();
        foreach (var option in ArgumentosDeCambio.Value.ToString().Split(','))
        {
            ColumnasSeleccionadas.Add(option.Trim());
        }
        ColumnasMostradas = ColumnasSeleccionadas;
    }


    private async Task HandleMenuItemsChanged(List<Columna> newMenuItems)
    {
        // Handle the changes in the MenuItems collection here
        Columnas = newMenuItems;
    }
    private string GetColumnValue(planes_cuentas cuenta, string columnName)
    {
        // Use reflection to get the value of the property with the specified name
        var property = cuenta.GetType().GetProperty(columnName);
        if (property != null)
        {
            return property.GetValue(cuenta)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    //Metodos del menu
    private bool IsEditing = false;
    private void ToggleEdit()
    {
        IsEditing = !IsEditing;
        foreach (var cuenta in Cuentas)
        {
            cuenta.IsEditable = !cuenta.IsEditable;
        }
        if (!IsEditing)
        {
            GetGridCuentas();
            CuentasCambiadas = new List<planes_cuentas>();
        }
    }
    private string ColorToggled()
    {
        return IsEditing ? "ButtonToggled" : string.Empty;
    }

    private List<planes_cuentas> CuentasCambiadas = new List<planes_cuentas>();
    private void HandleCellValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e, planes_cuentas cuenta, string ColumnaCambiada)
    {
        // Check if the cuenta object is not null
        if (cuenta != null)
        {
            // Get the type of the cuenta object
            Type cuentaType = cuenta.GetType();

            // Get the property info based on the column name
            var propertyInfo = cuentaType.GetProperty(ColumnaCambiada);

            // Check if the property exists and is writable
            if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.CanWrite)
            {
                // Convert the new value to the appropriate type
                object newValue = Convert.ChangeType(e.Value?.ToString(), propertyInfo.PropertyType);
                int index = CuentasCambiadas.FindIndex(c => c == cuenta);
                bool SeHaHechoCambiosSobreEstaCuenta = index != -1;
                propertyInfo.SetValue(cuenta, newValue);//Cambio el valor de cuenta para acomodar el cambio que se hizo en la tabla
                if (SeHaHechoCambiosSobreEstaCuenta)//Esto es apra que no haya tantos objetos en la lista
                {
                    CuentasCambiadas[index] = cuenta;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Add the cuenta object to the list of changed cuentas
                    CuentasCambiadas.Add(cuenta);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Property {ColumnaCambiada} not found or is read-only");
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var cuenta in Cuentas)
        {
            if (cuenta.IsEditable)
            {
                // Save the changes for the editable rows
                // Example: _context.Update(cuenta);
            }
        }
    }



    private void ToggleHijosVisibility(planes_cuentas cuenta)
    {
        cuenta.MostrarHijos = !cuenta.MostrarHijos;
    }
    ///
    /// </summary>W
    /// Recursive method to render account and its children
    /// <param name="cuenta"></param>
    /// <returns></returns> <summary>
    ///
    private RenderFragment RenderRow(planes_cuentas cuenta, int nivel = 1, bool EsElUltimo=false)
    {
        return builder =>
        {
            var children = Cuentas.Where(c => c.PDRE_CNTA == cuenta.CDGO_CNTA && c.NVEL_CNTA == cuenta.NVEL_CNTA + 1);

            // Render parent account
            builder.OpenElement(1, "tr");
                builder.OpenElement(2, "td");
                    builder.AddAttribute(3, "class", "ColumnaSticky");
                    builder.AddAttribute(4, "b-e13smserbq");
                    builder.OpenElement(5, "input");
                        builder.AddAttribute(6, "type", "checkbox");
                        builder.AddAttribute(7, "checked", BindConverter.FormatValue(cuenta.Seleccionado));
                        builder.AddAttribute(8, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<bool>(this, value => cuenta.Seleccionado = value, cuenta.Seleccionado));
                    builder.CloseElement();//close input
                builder.CloseElement(); // Close td
                builder.OpenElement(9, "td");
                    builder.AddAttribute(10, "class", "ColumnaSticky");
                    builder.AddAttribute(11, "b-e13smserbq");
                    builder.AddAttribute(12, "style", "left: 29px");

                    builder.AddContent(13, GenerarBotondDeExpandirYCodigoDeColumna(nivel, children, cuenta));
                builder.CloseElement();// Close td

                foreach (var columna in Columnas)
                {
                    if (columna.Seleccionado)
                    {
                        builder.OpenElement(14, "td");
                        builder.AddAttribute(15, "style", "white-space: nowrap; padding: 0px;");
                        builder.OpenElement(16, "input");
                        builder.AddAttribute(17, "style", "margin: 7px;");
                        if (cuenta.IsEditable)
                        {
                            builder.AddAttribute(18, "class", "editable");
                            builder.AddAttribute(19, "oninput", EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, (ChangeEventArgs e) => HandleCellValueChanged(e, cuenta, columna.Nombre)));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            builder.AddAttribute(20, "readonly", "true");
                            builder.AddAttribute(21, "class", "non-editable");
                        }
                        builder.AddAttribute(22, "b-e13smserbq");
                        builder.AddAttribute(23, "type", "text"); // Specify the type attribute
                        builder.AddAttribute(24, "value", GetColumnValue(cuenta, columna.Nombre)); // Bind the value attribute to a variable
                        builder.CloseElement(); // Close the input element
                        builder.CloseElement(); // Close td
                    }
                }
            builder.CloseElement(); // Close tr

            // Render children if expanded
            if (cuenta.MostrarHijos)
            {
                bool isLast = false;

                foreach (var child in children)
                {
                    if (!isLast && child == children.Last())
                    {
                        isLast = true;
                    }
                    builder.AddContent(25, RenderRow(child, child.NVEL_CNTA, isLast)); // Recursively render child
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private RenderFragment GenerarBotondDeExpandirYCodigoDeColumna(int NumeroDeDivs, IEnumerable<planes_cuentas> children, planes_cuentas cuenta)
    {
        RenderFragment renderFragment = builder =>
        {
            int depth = 1;
            string LineaGuia = "border-left: 2px solid black; margin-top: -10px;padding-top: 10px;margin-bottom: -10px;padding-bottom: 10px;";
            Action<int> generateDivs = null;
            generateDivs = currentDepth =>
            {
                if (currentDepth < NumeroDeDivs)
                {
                    builder.OpenElement(1, "div");
                    builder.AddAttribute(2, "style", $"display: flex;justify-content: flex-start;position: relative; margin-left: 20px;{LineaGuia}");
                    generateDivs(currentDepth + 1); // Recursively generate child divs
                    builder.CloseElement(); // Close div
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.OpenElement(1, "div");
                    builder.AddAttribute(2, "style", $"display: flex;justify-content: flex-start;position: relative; margin-left: 20px;{LineaGuia}");
                        builder.AddContent(3, "-");
                        if (children.Any())
                        {
                            builder.OpenElement(4, "button");
                                builder.AddAttribute(5, "class", "IconButton");
                                builder.AddAttribute(6, "b-e13smserbq");
                                builder.AddAttribute(6, "onclick", EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, () => ToggleHijosVisibility(cuenta)));
                                builder.OpenElement(7, "span");
                                builder.AddAttribute(8, "class", "oi oi-plus Icon");
                                builder.CloseElement(); // Close span
                            builder.CloseElement(); // Close button
                        }
                    builder.AddContent(9, cuenta.CDGO_CNTA);
                    builder.CloseElement(); // Close div
                }
            };

            // Start generating divs
            generateDivs(depth);
        };

        return renderFragment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I simply expect my table to update normally but it does not work

Yes, so do we all.  Welcome to the real world!

You've presented a *wall of code*, so it's difficult to see the wood from the trees.

This will definitely cause problems:

```cs
private async void GetGridCuentas()
```

Don't use the `async void method` pattern in any UI event handlers.

It should be:

```cs
private async Task GetGridCuentas()
```

See this answer for why - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74691716/13065781

And a similar answer on the topic - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76078709/13065781

##### Another issue

Using an auto-incrementer with the `RenderTreeBuilder` like this is a nono.  You need to use manual numbering.

```cs
builder.OpenElement(NumeroInstruccion++, "tr");
```

see this Ms Docs article for why not: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/advanced-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-8.0#the-problem-with-generating-sequence-numbers-programmatically